# Is TeXnicCenter dead?

Tags: texniccenter

I have been using TeXnicCenter with MikTeX for over 10 years and I love them. However, even if several terrific TeX editors are being migrated from Linux to Windows, TeXnicCenter hasn't received updates for more than one year. Actually, the last update dates back to September 29th, 2013 where the stable 2.02 version was released.

Is the TeXnicCenter project truly dead or just running slow?

Comment: It took about 4 years to go from 2.0 alpha to 2.0 stable, and it's a very small development team. I haven't seen any reports of its demise at [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=22), regardless.

Comment: *"It may seem to some of you that there is a large team behind TeXnicCenter. I can assure you, this is not the case. To sustain the development or better even speed it up, YOU need to help us. Documentation, Tutorials, Project Templates, Autocompletion-Templates, actual C++ programming, ... all input is welcome. [Contact us!](http://www.texniccenter.org/contact?si_contact_CID=1)"* This is [what the maintainer said](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=23856).

Comment: Please contact the maintainers for some feedback on this question and let us know the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in the comments.